# NDSolve`Iterate with shared variables

Tags: differential-equations, parallelization

I'm trying to parallelize a set of `NDSolve`s that share a few variables. Here is a short working example:

```
LaunchKernels[];    

n = 20; nAll = 27; m = 0; del = 1/10; theta = 2;
s = RandomReal[10, {100, nAll}]; SetSharedVariable[s];

map0 = Compile[{{y, _Real, 1}, {t, _Real}},
    Module[{cur}, 
     cur = If[t - .1 < # < t, Exp[(# - t)/0.1], 0.] & /@ y; 
     Tr[cur]],
    CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
map[t_?NumericQ, j_] := map0[s[[j]] + del, t];

Do[process[i] = Hold[NDSolve`Iterate[z, {m, m + del}];
     NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[z, "Forward"];] /. 
    z -> Symbol["eq" <> ToString[i]], {i, n}];
vars = Table[Symbol["eq" <> ToString[i]], {i, n}];
vars // Evaluate = 
  Table[NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{u'[t] == -u[t] + 
        Table[map[t,j], {j, nAll}].RandomReal[1, nAll], 
      u[0] == 0, 
      WhenEvent[u[t] > theta, {u[t] -> 0, AppendTo[s[[i]], t]}, 
       "LocationMethod" -> "StepEnd"]}, u, t, 
     Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", 
       "EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"}, MaxSteps -> 10^7] // 
    First, {i, n}];
```

Now, if I evaluate `process[5]` once, I get this

```
Hold[NDSolve`Iterate[eq5, {m, m + del}]; NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[eq5, "Forward"];]
```

which should iterate NDSolve once I apply `ReleaseHold` since `eq5` will point to `NDSolve'StateData["<" 0. ">"]`. This works fine in the main kernel:

```
process[5] // ReleaseHold
eq5

(*output*) NDSolve`StateData[<0.,0.1>]
```

I've been trying to parallelize this using something like:

```
SetSharedVariable[#] & /@ vars    
ParallelDo[process[i] // ReleaseHold, {i,n}]
```

but I couldn't find a way to keep the symbol and its values separate. I tried to change `eq1` with `eq[1]` but then `NDSolve'Iterate` doesn't accept it as an input. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

---

**edit:** The reason I want to share these variables is that I'll iterate this over different values of `m` and need the variables to be passed between kernels.

---

**edit2:** I have tried using `NDSolve'Reinitialize` to avoid setting the equations as shared variables. With same definitions:

```
Do[volt[i] = 0, {i, n}]; SetSharedFunction[volt];
temp = {}; Do[
 eq[i] = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{u'[t] == -u[t] + 
        Table[map[t,j], {j, nAll}].RandomReal[1, nAll], 
      u[0] == 0, 
      WhenEvent[u[t] > theta, {u[t] -> 0, AppendTo[s[[i]], t]}, 
       "LocationMethod" -> "StepEnd"]}, u, t, 
     Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", 
       "EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"}] // First, {i, n}];
DistributeDefinitions[eq, temp, map];

ParallelDo[
 Module[{state0 = eq[i], state1, saved = volt[i], sol}, 
  state1 = NDSolve`Reinitialize[state0, {u[m] == saved}] // First; 
  NDSolve`Iterate[state1, {m, m +del}]; 
  volt[i] = 
   NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state1, "Forward"] // Values // First;
  If[temp != {}, s[[i]] = Join[s[[i]], temp]; temp = {}]], {i, n}]
```

which still doesn't work. NDSolve doesn't seem to accept `s` as a shared variable.

Comment: What do you expect to get?

Comment: Your issue is in your call to `SetSharedVariable`. You can no longer make use of the list `vars` which does not point to a symbol any more. Try Replace[ToExpression[Table["m"<>i, ...], StandardForm, Hold], Hold[v_]:>SetDharedVar[v], 1]` or some standard pattern like that. Also make sure to read up on `Hold` and delayed evaluation or whatever the tutorial is called.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Please see my update. I got rid of that expression but still can't get NDSolve to work inside ParallelDo, probably because 's' is shared

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may operate on lists so you do not need a symbol for every solution.

With

```
n = 20; nAll = 27; m = 0; del = 1/10; theta = 2;
```

and `map` and `map0` as in OP. Then define `volt` and `state` as lists.

```
volt = Range@n;

state =
 Function[{i},
   NDSolve`ProcessEquations[
     {
      u'[t] == -u[t] + Table[map[t, j], {j, nAll}].RandomReal[1, nAll],
      u[0] == 0,
      WhenEvent[u[t] > theta, {u[t] -> 0, AppendTo[s[[i]], t]}, 
       "LocationMethod" -> "StepEnd"]
      },
     u, t,
     Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", 
       "EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"}] // First
   ] /@ Range@n;
```

Next a result list, `res`,  is setup.  This is the only variable that has a *side-effect* from `ParallelDo` so is the only one that needs `SetSharedVariable`.

```
res = ConstantArray[Null, n];
LaunchKernels[];
SetSharedVariable[res];
```

Finally `ParallelDo` is called. Note that since `` NDSolve`ProcessSolutions `` can take the longest of the three `NDSolve` steps its result is not directly assigned to the shared variable, `res`. Doing so could lock `res` in the other kernels for extended periods.  Instead the result is assigned to a temporary variable, `r`, for the potentially extended processing and then quickly assigned to the shared variable.

```
ParallelDo[
 Module[{state1, r},
  state1 = 
   NDSolve`Reinitialize[state[[i]], {u[m] == volt[[i]]}] // First;
  NDSolve`Iterate[state1, {m, m + del}];
  r = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state1, "Forward"] // Values // First;
  res[[i]] = r;
  ],
 {i, n}]
```

`ParallelDo` automatically `DistributeDefinitions` on variables in its body. Therefore, the above solution works best when these variables (`state`, `volt`, `r`, `m`,`del`) are not memory intensive.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason, WhenEvent is not working inside ParallelDo even with this setup. I want to reset u[t] to 0 when it hits the threshold (theta).

Comment: @thedude I agree that `WhenEvent` is not firing in parallel but is firing in serial.  I am reporting to Wolfram to see if this is a known issue with workaround.