# How to trigger WhenEvent for NDSolve in parallel?

Tags: differential-equations, parallelization, event-detection

Say I have a system of differential equations that I need to solve for different initial conditions and say the process is sufficiently expensive and I have sufficiently many that I am calculating in parallel.  This system contains a `WhenEvent`.

As minimal example a model for a bouncing ball with different acceleration due to gravity.

```
state =
  First@NDSolve`ProcessEquations[
      {
       y''[t] == #, y[0] == 5,
       y'[0] == 0,
       WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, y'[t] -> -0.95 y'[t]]
       },
      y, t,
      Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", "EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"}
      ] & /@ {-9.81, -5.5, -3.3};
```

This evaluates in serial without issue with the initial height being varied. Code below is setup for parallel processing.

```
resS = ConstantArray[Null, 3];
Do[
 Module[{state1, r},
  state1 =
   NDSolve`Reinitialize[state[[i]], {y[0] == i 10}] // First;
  NDSolve`Iterate[state1, {0, 10}];
  r = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state1];
  resS[[i]] = r;
  ],
 {i, 3}]
Plot[y[t] /. #, {t, 0, 10}] & /@ resS // GraphicsRow
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The affect of `WhenEvent` is seen with each bounce when `y[t] == 0`.

However in parallel the `WhenEvent` does not trigger.

```
resP = ConstantArray[Null, 3];
LaunchKernels[];
SetSharedVariable[resP];

ParallelDo[
 Module[{state1, r},
  state1 =
   NDSolve`Reinitialize[state[[i]], {y[0] == i 10}] // First;
  NDSolve`Iterate[state1, {0, 10}];
  r = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state1];
  resP[[i]] = r;
  ],
 {i, 3}]
Plot[y[t] /. #, {t, 0, 10}] & /@ resP // GraphicsRow
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

`WhenEvent` never triggers and the ball falls through the floor forever.

Any ideas on how to trigger `WhenEvent` for `NDSolve` in parallel without reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Seems that `Parallel*` is having trouble with ``NDSolve`StateData``. It's not even related to `WhenEvent`. A possible boiling down: ``state = First@
     NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{y''[t] == #, y[0] == 5, y'[0] == 0}, y, t] &[-9.81];

resP = ParallelTable[
  NDSolve`Iterate[state, {0, 10}];
  NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state], {1}]``. `DistributedContexts` option doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is complex. It's all easier

```
g = {-9.81, -5.5, -3.3}; y0 = {10, 20, 30};
ParallelTable[{sol = 
   NDSolve[{y''[t] == g[[i]], y[0] == y0[[i]], y'[0] == 0, 
     WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, y'[t] -> -0.95 y'[t]]}, y, {t, 0, 10}]; 
  Plot[y[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}]}, {i, 3}]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't what OP wants. Those ``NDSolve`ProcessEquations`` etc. cannot be circumvented. Notice this question is probably a follow-up of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/188430/1871).

Comment: @xzczd I do not know what OP wants, but he incorrectly uses parallel computing.

Comment: @xzczd You are correct that the above is not in line with what I am seeking. Keep in mind that the example is just a minimal example to demonstrate the issue. The real problem will have multiple ``NDSolve`Reinitialize`` calls per system.

Comment: @AlexTrounev The actual system is sufficiently expensive such that there is a performance gain when utilizing the ``NDSolve`*`` functions instead of `NDSolve` directly.

Comment: @Edmund Are you sure there will be a time gain?